# External Function Calls

Tags: solidity, remix

I am going through a tutorial and just need some clarification on the below code - particularly the second line. Could someone take me through this very slowly?

```
    function deposit() public payable {}

    function depositOnContractOne(address _contractOne) public { 
        ContractOne one = ContractOne(_contractOne);
        one.deposit{value: 10, gas: 100000}(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
ContractOne one = ContractOne(_contractOne);
```

creates an instance of the ContractOne and names it 'one'.
So in 'one' is all the functions that are in 'ContractOne'.

The next line

```
one.deposit{value: 10, gas: 100000}();
```

calls the deposit function from the ContractOne. The deposit() function in ContractOne must be external and payable since there is some value attached to it.

So, to summarize, your function 'depositOnContractOne' instantiates a 'ContractOne' at address '_contractOne' and names it 'one', then send 10 wei while calling the function 'deposit' of 'ContractOne'.

Hope this helps